# Reading a particular word from a text file in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a file(version.h) whose contents looks like this:

```
#ifndef _VERSION_H_
#define _VERSION_H_

// Date with short Git SHA hash
// '*' at end indicates changed files in repository.
#define _VERSION_STRING "2019-09-24-9uy8cbc"

#endif // _VERSION_H_
```

I want to read the version value i.e _VERSION_STRING value.
i was thinking for searching for the word _VERSION_STRING in the file and reading the value after it to get the version number.
Is there any other way to do this. Any help is much appreciated since i am very new to java scripting.Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use the following regular expression: `/(?:\n|\r|^)#define\s+_version_string\s+"([^"]+)"(?:\r|\n|$)/`

- `(?:\n|\r|^)`: start of new line (cr or lf) or start of text
- `#define\s+_version_string\s+`: match the string `#define _VERSION_STRING` regardless of the number of spaces
- `"([^"]+)"`: match the quotes and get everything inside the quotes.
- `(?:\r|\n|$)`: start of new line (lf or cr) or end of text

```js
var text = `#ifndef _VERSION_H_
#define _VERSION_H_

// Date with short Git SHA hash
// '*' at end indicates changed files in repository.
#define _VERSION_STRING "2019-09-24-9uy8cbc"

#endif // _VERSION_H_`;

var result = /(?:\n|\r|^)#define\s+_version_string\s+"([^"]+)"(?:\r|\n|$)/i.exec(text);

console.log(result ? result[1] : "version not found");
```